# Configuring tools with an external file in cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm trying to figure out how to configure a tool to run whenever a request is received in cherrypy, using an external configuration file.  I've read through the examples in the documentation, but these all embed the configuration into the source file, rather than a separate configuration file.  I've read that tools can be configured externally, but I haven't found any examples.

Taking the example on the [wiki](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/CustomTools), I'd like to be able to do something logically like this:

```
tools.print_path = cherrypy.Tool('on_start_resource', {what goes here?})
```

Suppose I have a file named 'mytools.py' in my PYTHONPATH, which I can import using 'import mytools', and in this file I have a simple "def print_path(multiplier=1)" method.  What do I put in the "{what goes here?}" spot?  I've tried variations on mytools.print_path and the best I get is this:

```
CherryPy Checker:
The config entry 'tools.print_path' may be invalid, because the 'print_path' tool was not found.
section: [/]
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no facility inside of a config file to instantiate a Tool (the `cherrypy.Tool(...)` part). You need to do that in code. Your 'mytools.py' file should look like this:

```
def print_path(multiplier=1):
    ...
cherrypy.tools.print_path = cherrypy.Tool('on_start_resource', print_path)
```

...and then your config file is used to turn the Tool on for a given URL (and its children):

```
[/]
tools.print_path.on: True
tools.print_path.multiplier: 23
```

Just make sure you 'import mytools' before processing the config file in your startup script.